# Problems with passing json to php and receiving data from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

My problem is how JQuery knows when to receive data, when I watch the browser's console I see that GET call is first and then the POST call is second.
It should be POST first, then GET.

I tried solving my problem with .ready,and with some IF statements and so on but I still have not achieved what I wanted to achieve. Should I use some events?

My Javscript:

```
 (function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("form#userdata").submit(function(){
       $.post( "savedata.php", $("form#userdata").serialize())
         .done(function( data ) {
           alert( "Send data" + data );
        });
       return false;
       alert("Error by passing data to php");
     });

 })})(jQuery);

 $.when($.ajax("savedata.php")).then(function(){
     $.get("savedata.php", function(data){
            alert("Php returns validation errors:+data);
     });
 });
```

My php script:

```
 // Get POST data
 $postData = $_POST;

 // Print out for testing
 // print_r($postData);

 // Read data
 $fistname = $_POST['firstname'];
 $surname=$_POST['lastname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];

 // VALIDATION


 // Build return array and return JSON
 $returnData = $postData;

 //print(json_encode($returnData));
 echo json_encode($returnData);
 ?>
```

Comment: Did you even try to see your browser console??

Comment: I am watching all the time..

Comment: You didn't get a syntax error because of the missing doublequote? Was that just a copying error when you copied to SO?

Comment: Ok, let me get this... Your PHP script will return same data, despite you have an validation error or an successful validation??

Comment: You are mistaken if you think that you need POST (to send data) and another GET (to get data). Everything could easily be achieved using one POST or GET call to the script. You can directly return (echo/print) the result with this one call

Comment: * By same data i mean, it will ALWAYS return an encoded JSON with $returnData variable

Comment: Alexandre Wiechers Vaz no!  If the validation is fine I will only put on page that new costumer has been add to mysql if there is validation error then I return zeros or ones. I return something like tihs Array={1,0,1,0,1,1,1}. So lets say that "1" means that input data is fine, if it's "0" that means that user did't complited that field or the value if filed isn't corrent(you cant pust your name Alexandre45. Am I clear?ž

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**PHP:**

```
// Get POST data
 $postData = $_POST;

 // Print out for testing
 // print_r($postData);

 // Read data
 $fistname = $_POST['firstname'];
 $surname=$_POST['lastname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];

 // VALIDATION

 if(//validationError){
    echo json_encode(array('error' => //Your error message here));
    exit();
 }
 $returnData = $postData;

 //print(json_encode($returnData));
 echo json_encode(array('success' => $returnData));
 ?>
```

Then...

**JS:**

```
(function($) {

   $(document).ready(function() {

     $("form#userdata").submit(function(){

       $.post("savedata.php", $("form#userdata").serialize())
        .done(function( data ) {
           if(data.error)
              alert("Validation error: " + data.error);
           else
              alert( "Send data" + data.success );
        })
        .fail(function(){
           alert("Error by passing data to php");
        });
     });

 })})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thx for your post! Oke I use your post as strucutre, but know says error ba passing data to php, now what should i do?

Comment: Take a look at your console "Network" tab and see what is the error returned by the ajax call!

Comment: It says status canceled, type pending, initator jq...js:8706 script and other unimportant data.

Comment: Ok, if it's saying "Error by parsing data", something is going wrong in your ajax call. It probably throws an error on console (One 4xx o4 5xx. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). What is the error??

Comment: Ok the post is fine 200, but I get error NS_ERROT_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aboted by user nsPrompter.js:440 (did't click any popup), and there is syntaxerror using //@ to indicate source map url pragmas is cepreceted user //# instead. jquery.min.js:1

Comment: The last one is an core jquery error, nothing to do with your code. Now, the first one seems to be an firefox error caused by some inconsistency during an alert call... Try to remove the "data" elements from alerts and see if it works.

Comment: I still get same problems in console.

Comment: Server side is ok(Validating and inserting data on mysql)?? What an awkward error, never heard about it oO

Comment: Yes validating is working fine and also all stuf about mysql(make connection, inserting data, closing connection). I don't know what should I do and this staf should be done by tomorow...

Comment: You need to alert that data was inserted?? It really seems to be an core browser component error. Try it in an different browser or maybe try to give the message using another method, like using console.log(I'd recommend alertify.js: http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ notifications :D )

Comment: No i don't need but, i would like. But errors absolutetly i should show on page.

Comment: You can try to use alertify or maybe another plugin to show custom notifications and alerts :) Have you tried other browsers?? Same error?

Comment: Now I am trying this alertify but it seems that it isnt' working.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is called unconditionally, while the page is loading, because you didn't put it in an event handler.

`$.post` is only called when you submit the `#userdata` form, because it's called from the `.submit()` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You have your script incorrect

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("form#userdata").submit(function(){
       $.post( "savedata.php", $("form#userdata").serialize())
         .done(function( data ) {
           alert( "Send data" + data );
        });
       return false;
       alert("Error by passing data to php");
     });

 })})(jQuery);

 $.when($.ajax("savedata.php")).then(function(){
     $.get("savedata.php", function(data){
            alert("Php returns validation errors:"+data); // You did not close the string literal and it would throw an error
     });
 });
```

Comment: Please compare the line with the last alert with your script and you'll easily see

Comment: He showed how it should be: he added a doublequote after `validation errors:`